# Resource.Designer.cs file not updating correctly

Tags: xamarin.forms, zxing

I'm trying to build a simple barcode scanner using Xamarin forms and I'm using ZXing Library (I copied/added the Dlls manually).
when i build the project i get the following errors:

`'Resource.Id' does not contain a definition for'contentFrame'
'Resource.Layout' does not contain a definition for 'zxingscanneractivitylayout'
'Resource.Layout' does not contain a definition for 'zxingscannerfragmentlayout'`

I did my research before posting this, I know that the error has something to do with the "Resource.Designer.cs" file not being updated but I honestly don't know how to fix this.
I also found this old post with the same problem
[[Unknown globals when installing ZXing Scanner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31855307/unknown-globals-when-installing-zxing-scanner][1])
but nothing suggested worked for me.

Any Idea, how can this error be fixed,  Thanks for your help.

Edit : I'm using Visual Studio Enterprise 2015 and Xamarin Forms v2.2.0.45

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just update to Zxing.Net.Mobile 2.1.0.1 beta **prelease** and the errors will disappear.

The problem is widely known

[Xamarin bugzilla](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=39910#c30)

[Issue on Github repository of Zxing](https://github.com/Redth/ZXing.Net.Mobile/issues/344)